# How to fire alarms after 2 to 3 day

Tags: android, notifications, alarm

I need to execute a notification every 2 days when the use register an item and execute a notification every 3 days if the user has not use the app.

currently im using this to set the alarm notification

```
Calendar calendar1 = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar1.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 7);
    calendar1.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
    calendar1.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
    if (calendar1.before(calendar))
        calendar1.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, Dog_alert1.class).setAction("dog1");
    PendingIntent dog1 = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 100, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    final AlarmManager alarm1 = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 19) {
        alarm1.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar1.getTimeInMillis(), dog1);
    } else {
        alarm1.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar1.getTimeInMillis(), dog1);
    }
```

Now how can I fire this alarm after 3 days?

Comment: Call `calendar1.add(Calendar.DATE, 3);` after you adjust for today.

Comment: oh ok so if  I want to change in it into any days ill change just change the value of date is that right?

Comment: Also if im going to use date format like this "2018-23-04 12:30 " how can I  make the alarm execute after 3 days of the set date and time?